# Is there any way to pass string with quotes and spaces correctly as param in the shell script

Tags: shell, sh

Description is quite abstract, actually I'm trying to pass params to the `%configure` macro in the RPM .spec file. But the behavior is just the same.

Script like that using `sh -x`:

```
#! /bin/sh

VAR1=" \
--enable-modules=dir so com \
--disable-userdir"

./configure $VAR1
```

gives me:

```
+./configure --enable-modules=dir so com --disable-userdir
```

What I need is:

```
+./configure --enable-modules='dir so com' --disable-userdir
```

Question: Is there any way to pass quotes and spaces correctly? Placing quotes around `'dir so com'` in `$VAR1` ruins all the string. $"" does nothing, qoutes quote nearest character group without spaces, etc. I tried nearly everything.

### **EDIT:**

Try before recommend anything, please. If that was simple it won't be a problem. And I didn't mean echo, I need to pass params it to a macros/external script. Sed/cat chemistry are acceptable, but I can't call `./configure` directly through 'backquotes' or somehow else as `rpmbuild` calls it itself with some additional params. Passing params without qoutes works fine.

```
VAR1=" \
--enable-modules=dir so com \
--disable-userdir"
```

does:

```
$ sh -x test.sh
+ VAR1=' --enable-modules="dir so com" --disable-dir --disable-actions --disable-userdir'
+ ./configure '--enable-modules="dir' so 'com"' --disable-dir --disable-actions --disable-userdir`
```

Comment: Please notice that `sh -x` won't show you how arguments are split (at least my version of `sh`). Try `sh -x -c 'echo "one two"'` and then `bash -x -c 'echo "one two"'`. Instead, make a function like `debug_args() { while test $# -gt 0 ; do echo "$1"; shift ; done } ` and use it like `debug_args "one two"` to see how any other function would get called. Instead of spawning a new shell with `sh -x -c ...` you can also `set -x` in the current shell.

Answer (score 2):

you can just escape your 'quotes within the quote', like such

```
#!/bin/sh

VAR1=" \
--enable-modules=\"dir so com\" \
--disable-userdir"

echo $VAR1
```

Comment: Right. "\" is the strongest escape. Followed by `'`, followed by `"`.

Comment: Try before recommend, please. If that was so simple it won't be a problem. And I didn't mean echo, I need to pass it to macros/external script.
`$ sh -x test.sh
+ VAR1=' --enable-modules="dir so com" --disable-dir --disable-actions --disable-userdir'
+ ./configure '--enable-modules="dir' so 'com"' --disable-dir --disable-actions --disable-userdir`

Comment: That won't work, because the quotes will get passed into the arguments

Answer (score 2):

No, I'm afraid. In `./configure $VAR1` the variable `$VAR1` will be split at IFS characters and result into zero or more words. That means split **strictly** at the IFS characters. Quote/escape recognition happens before variable expansion, that means that quotes or escapes as part of the variable's value don't have any effect (they stand for themselves). It is too late, run!

What you could do alternatively is something like

```
set -- "--enable-modules=dir so com" --disable-userdir
./configure "$@"
```

which would overwrite your positional parameters, such that `$1` and `$2` are the two arguments following the `--`, and then uses `"$@"` which expands back to exactly those two words.

You could also use `bash` arrays instead of misusing the set array (`sh` to my knowledge has only that one global array) but I've got the impression you have been able to preserve some taste and don't want to use bash.

You could also do something like

```
VAR1="--enable-modules=dir so com%--disable-userdir"
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=%
./configure $VAR1
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

But, yeah.

Comment: The closest match is `./configure --enable-modules= 'dir so com' --disable-userdir`, so I guess there is no way to accomplish that. I'm trying to inject backspace char, but it got wiped out before passing. Another way is try to pass double quotes, but I'm not sure **./configure** will accept it

Comment: @Nanako: I don't understand what you are talking about, and I think you didn't get me correctly. Please read again, I know I'm right ;-). And no, passing quotes to scripts won't help. Quotes are there to protect arguments from being split.

Answer (score 0):

Pick either of the following strategy.

### Replace positional arguments

Start a subshell where you replace positional parameters and use the special expansion `"$@"` to start your program.

```
(set -- "--enable-modules=dir so com" --disable-userdir; ./configure "$@")
```

### Use a special value of IFS

Pick a character absent of your arguments, assume `|` will do. Now prepare your argument vector splitting each argument with `|` and start your script accordingly:

```
 configure_argv="--enable-modules=dir so com|--disable-userdir"
 IFS='|' ./configure $configure_argv
```

### Use xargs

Recall that `xargs` can split arguments at character `\000`. This gives

```
 configure_argv()
 {
     printf '--enable-modules=dir so com\000'
     printf '--disable-userdir\000'
 }
 configure_argv | xargs -0 ./configure
```